# getElementByID.readOnly in array

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to create a list of input ID's and use it in array, to make them readOnly - but the result is error -> "cannot read property 'readOnly' of null". 
Can you give me a hint what I should change?

```
script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $(function(){
     var index, len;
        $.get('/SomeList.txt', function(data){
            var SomeList = data.split('\n');
            for (index = 0, len = SomeList.length; index < len; index++) {
           document.getElementById(SomeList[index]).readOnly = true;
}
        });

    });

     });
     </script>
```

and txt file contains name of input ID:

```
TextFieldName
TextFieldEmail
TextFieldDepartment
TextFieldOffice
```

Comment: if you're using `jQuery`, why don't you try `$('#'+SomeList[index]).attr('readonly', true)`?

Comment: try setAttribute('readonly', 'true')

Comment: As the error points out, `document.getElementById(SomeList[index])` is returning `null`.  This could be because of poor formatting in `SomeList.txt` (a stray newline perhaps?) or a missing element on the page.  You could always check to see if the element exists before trying to change its property (e.g. `var el = document.getElementById(SomeList[index]); if(el) el.readOnly = true;`).  Unfortunately, without more information, it's hard to tell why the `getElementById` call is returning `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have some elements with the given IDs you must check if the element exists first before doing

```
document.getElementById(SomeList[index]).readOnly = true;
```

so replace that line with

```
var myElement = document.getElementById(SomeList[index]);
if(myElement == null) {
    return;
}
myElement.readOnly = true;
```

That should work like following example where the IDs come from an array and the second one will not mach because of `xxxxx` so it's not readonly. But all the others are.

```js
var dataArray = [
  'TextFieldName',
  'TextFieldEmailxxxxx',
  'TextFieldDepartment',
  'TextFieldOffice'
];

dataArray.forEach(function(id){
    var myElement = document.getElementById(id);
    if(myElement == null) {
        return;
    }
    myElement.readOnly = true;
});
```

```html
<input id="TextFieldName" type="text">
<input id="TextFieldEmail" type="text">
<input id="TextFieldDepartment" type="text">
<input id="TextFieldOffice" type="text">
```

Comment: Thank you i'll use this. I''ve changed txt to one row (with "," as separator) and everething works fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```js
var id_array=["email","country"];
for (i = 0; i <id_array.length; i++) {
           document.getElementById(id_array[i]).readOnly = true;
}
```

```html
  Email: <input type="text" id="email" value="test@mail.com"><br> 
  Country: <input type="text" id="country" value="Norway" >
```

it is working fine in my case.
i think there may be whitespace in your array items because your are reading them from file.so try to trim array items.
and make sure you assign id's to input elements

Comment: The problem was in txt file, after i changed txt and data.split('\n') to data.split(',') everething is ok. Thank you for your answer!